# w2k16 - KB4480961 not offered via windows update

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

Hello we have just done patching of our customer's servers. We noticed atound half of windows 2016 did not download and install this big update KB4480961. The customer's security department is worried hwy is that so. I wonder if that's a bug or something  reasonable makes this patch not applicable/needed for these servers?
The difference between those which got this update is they don't have KB4483229. Does it work that way that after installing KB4480961 the KB4483229 disappears from the get-hotfix list?

Comment: Can you confirm if `KB4480977` (January, 2019) was installed on the servers, which did not download the KB4480961? Also, `KB4480961` supersedes KB4483229, which means if the former is installed, the latter will not install, and not get mentioned in Get-Hotfix list!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft explained this:

*"Deployment Notes

The Delta package for this update assumes you have deployed the December 19th  security update (KB4483229). If you have not deployed the December 19th security update (KB4483229), then you must apply the Full Update for this release and cannot use the Delta package."*

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480961/windows-10-update-kb4480961)

In plain English:
Cumulative means everything before it. Delta means a smaller package that contains only the fixes for the selected month.
The delta updates are applicable to the computers that have cumulative or delta updates installed for the previous month.

Comment: thanks but I am not sure how to understand it. Does it mean that if server already has KB4483229 then it DOES NOT automatically install KB4480961? I see the delta has the same KB name, so KB4480961 should be ready for installation anyway. but just the smaller version (delta), right?

Comment: WSUS should have both versions of one KB - delta and cumulative? Or just cumulative? There is just cumulative on our WSUS

Comment: in product classification "security updates" is checked. There is no way to choose delta or cumulative

Comment: I added some details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks but I understand what is the difference between delta and cumulative. No need to keep explain that further. My question was different - why some of our servers did not download and install neither package. But I guess it must be some temporary windows update problem in our environment and it's not normal...

Comment: I'm rating Windows update reliability for anything made since W10 appeared as low to very low. I'm recommending to go LTSB (https://www.computerworld.com/article/3250464/microsoft-windows/faq-windows-10-ltsb-explained.html) due to that.